# How to put pickle dict value into an object

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I am using pickle to dump a dictionary object into a txt file.  I need to grab the dictionary from the file and extract only certain values and put them inside of an object as a string.

My dictionary looks something like this:

```
obj_dict = { 'name': 'MYID', 'value': 'usdf23444', 
             'name': 'MYID2', 'value' : 'asdfh3479' }
```

Part of the dilemma I have is that there are two `'name'` and two `'value'` in the dictionary and I need to grab each separately.

Here is the code I am using:

```
import pickle

filepath = file.txt
output = open(filepath, 'rb')
obj_dict = pickle.load(output)
for i in obj_dict:
    NewString = "VALUE1=" + i['value1'] + "VALUE2=" + i['value2']

print(NewString)
```

I know this code doesn't work, I'm more showing what I need my end result to look like but basically I need each value to be put into a string that I can use later.  How can I reference `'value1'` and `'value2`' correctly?  Also I am getting this error when trying to just get one 'value':
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

**EDIT FOR COMMENT 2**

I'm not sure if that's true, I can run this code:

```
output = open(filepath, 'rb')
obj_dict = pickle.load(output)
for i in obj_dict:
    print(i['value'])
```

and my output is:

```
usdf23444
asdfh3479
```

Comment: you can't have multiple keys with the same name in a dictionary. When you create the dict (pre-pickling), print it to screen and see that you actually don't have both values in there, the second one will overwrite the first.

Comment: @bananafish see edit above ^  The issue is I don't create the dict :/ that's just how it is.

Comment: It is impossible, `dict` can not have two different objects with the same key

Comment: does it matter that it's in binary?  This is a response from an html request.  It would be something like this: `'MYID' : 'usdf23444' ; 'asdfh3479'`  but in the `dict` it appears as two values with the same key

Comment: @SenorPenguin Well, I can guarantee you that the dict does not have multiple keys with the same name. From your message it looks more like it is a list of lists? if you print the raw data structure (currently called "obj_dict"), what do you get? what is type(obj_dict)?

Comment: @bananafish Honestly it may be a list, sorry I'm not sure.  If I `print(obj_dict)` I get: `[{'name': 'MYID', 'value': 'usdf23444', 'name': 'MYID2', 'value' : 'asdfh3479'}]`

Comment: @SenorPenguin No worries! Surrounding brackets means it's a list, curly braces mean dict. So a list of dicts here. See my answer below, it should do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the update, it looks like it is a list of dicts. Try:

```
strings = ["VALUE{}={}".format(i, d['value']) for i, d in enumerate(obj_dict)]
```

Comment: if I `print(strings)` I get: `['VALUE0=usdf23444', 'VALUE1=asdfh3479']`  Is it possible for me to now reference these individually?

Comment: @SenorPenguin you can, with strings[0] and strings[1]. But if you want to look them up you may want to use a dict yourself as well. Perhaps you want to create a dict with the names as keys? Try this (untested): `{r['name']: r['value'] for r in obj_dict}`.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks because this ended up working.  Another question though, when I print each one I get `VALUE0=usdf23444` Is there anyway I can make it so that the `"VALUE0="` isn't there?  I'm probably just going to use a trim function but didn't know if there was a way I could change the code to have just the value.  Or maybe I could get it to say just `"VALUE="` without the 0 or 1?  Thanks again!

Comment: nvm I got it working with cutting that part out, it works perfect now